# DIV changing onclick with external page as a variable

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have this code that is changing the content of the DIV based on an external page:

```
<a href="" onclick="return false" onmousedown="loadexteranlPage() "> external page</a>
```

and

```
function loadexternalPage() {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
document.getElementById('main_frame').innerHTML = 
xmlhttp.responseText;
}}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "externalpage.html", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

How can I update this code in the way the function get a variable as an external page instead?
something like this??

```
<a href="" onclick="return false" onmousedown="loadexteranlPage(externalpage) ">  Link to external page</a>

function loadexternalPage(externalpage) {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
document.getElementById('main_frame').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
} }
xmlhttp.open("GET", externalpage, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

or with method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
loadxtPage("popup.html"); 
$("#main_frame").click(loadxtPage("externalpage.html"));
})
```

Comment: You could actually use the "href" attribute, since the click event is overriden anyway. But the real question is where you need the URLs to be specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the href attribute:

Pass the event here:

```
<a href="externalpage.html" onclick="return false" onmousedown="loadexteranlPage(event) ">  Link to external page</a>
```

Use the events' attribute to get the URL:

```
function loadexternalPage(event) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('main_frame').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", event.target.href, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

This is one possible solution. It really depends on where you need to specify the URL.

Comment: thank you for the answer but I cannot see where you are calling the page that in my situation is called externalpage.html.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to pass the address to "href" element, it is edited now.

Comment: I would like to specify the URL in the href when I am calling the function, in the way any page.html that I am writing into the function get translated as a variable for the script